# Doesn't show both style and class when added div to my HTML using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Doesn't show both style and class in console when added div to my HTML using JS, also bootstrap classes don't work,

Here is the code for `main_page`:

```
<?php
require "connection.php";?>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <?php require "header.php"; ?>
</header>
<main>
    <?php require "main_content.php"; ?>
</main>
<footer>
    <?php ?>
</footer>
</body>
<script src = "js/change_avatar_settings.js"></script>
<script src = "js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script src = "js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Here is the code for `main_content.php`:

```
<main class = "container mt-5">
<div class = "display-none" id = "change_display">
    <div id = "change_avatar" class = "container">
    </div>
</div>  
</main>
```

Here is the JS code called from onclick function (which is in header) (no problem from calling a function), the problem is in that both class - "armen" and style doesn't work in my html, but div with form is created without any issues.

```
function changeAvatar() {
    document.getElementById('change_avatar').innerHTML += '<div class = "armen" style = "width:500px;height:500px;"><form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="image"><input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="avatar_btn"><input type="submit" value="Delete Image" name="del_avatar_btn"></form></div>'
}
```

Comment: Is that your Full HTML document?  You are missing a closing `</html>` tag and you are entirely missing the `<body> ... </body>` tags

Comment: What is the problem exactly ?

Comment: done, sorry for making you misunderstand added both HTML closing tag and body

Comment: the problem starts from function, it doesn't add class = "armen" and style, but div itself with inner form is created without issues

Comment: Have you tried to use affectation (=) instead of concatenation (+=) ?

Comment: Yes i tried, doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work just fine when I call the function.  The `class` and `style` are added which is shown by the red border I put around it which selects by that class and shows that the `height` and `width` are set on it.

```js
function changeAvatar(){
    document.getElementById('change_avatar').innerHTML += `
<div class = "armen" style = "width:500px;height:500px;">
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="avatar_btn">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete Image" name="del_avatar_btn">
  </form>
</div>`
}

changeAvatar();
```

```css
.armen {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="change_avatar" class="container"></div>
```

Comment: I guess have to refresh mamp, thank you however

Comment: doesn't work, don't know why